# What is the best way to recognize and convert these "minimum" double values into C# Double.MinValue?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double

I have a database table that needs to be converted into current form.  This table has three columns that are of type Double (it's `Pervasive.SQL`, if anyone cares).

My problem is that this table has been around for a long time, and it's been acted upon by code going back some 15 years or better.

Historically, we have always used `Double.MinValue` (or whatever language equivalent at the time) to represent `"blank"` values provided by the user.  The absence of a value, in other words, is actually stored as a value that we can recognize later and react to intelligently.

So, today my problem is that I need to loop through these records and insert them into a newly created table (this is the "conversion" I spoke of).  However, I am not seeing consistent values in the tables I am converting.  Here are the ones I know of for sure:

```
2.2250738585072014E-308
3.99285938963E-313
3.99099435427E-313
1.1125369292536007E-308
-5.389000690742776E279
2.104687961E-314
```

Now, I recognize that there are other ways that `Double.MinValue` might exist or at least be represented.  Having done some google searches, I found that the first one is another representation of `Double.MinValue` (actually `DBL_MIN` referenced here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bs3y5ya(v=vs.100).aspx).

I don't want to get too long-winded, so I'll solicit questions if this is not enough information to help me.  Suffice it to say, I need a reliable way of spotting all of the previous values of "minimum" and replace them with the C# `Double.MinValue` constant as I am looping these data rows.

If it proves to be `dataRow["Value"] < someConstant`, then so be it.  But I'll let the math theorists help me out with that determination.

Thank you for the time.

**EDIT:**

Here's what I am doing with these values as I find them.  It's part of a generic method that assembles values to be written to the database:

```
else if (c.DataType == typeof(System.Double))
{
    if (inRow[c] == DBNull.Value)
        retString += @"NULL";
    else
    {
        Double d;
        if (Double.TryParse(inRow[c].ToString(), out d))
        retString += d.ToStringFull();
    }
}
```

Until now, it simply accepted them.  And that's bad because when the application finds them, they look like acceptable data, and *not* like Double.MinValue.  Therefore, not seen as blanks.  But that's what they are.

Comment: What if you just did a `SELECT * From Table ORDER BY YourColumn` to see the data in ascending order.  It'd probably be fairly easy to spot where there was a *huge* gap and real data began.

Comment: Question: how common was it that the table had a Doulbe.MinValue inserted to represent the "null"? If this was common thing, there should be at least one easy way I can think of.

Comment: I hope that you are going to store them as `null` in the new tables

Comment: @MikeChristensen Perhaps I didn't communicate well.  I'm not analyzing the data, I just need to spot these "blanks" and replace with Double.MinValue.  The problem is that the list of values I provided equate to no constant in C# that I am aware of, and thus I cannot recognize them directly without hard-coding every one.

Comment: @GregKramida Quite common.  These fields are just 3 of many in the record.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Unfortunately no.  In fact, that's the reason I must ask in the first place.  This use of a "blank" value persists, and today is Double.MinValue...hence my need to replace.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - Well, first you need to fix this mess.  It's a huge technical debt that shouldn't be ignored.  Second, that's what I'm saying; look at the values with a query, look at where the cut off is, then make *that* your constant in C#.

Comment: How small are the smallest "real" values? Are any negative values "real"? Is 0 "real"?

Comment: Doesn't your database support null?

Comment: @Don, I think Mike's solution is actually quite neat if you do have common SQL tools available to you. I'm not an expert on Pervasive.SQL, but sounds like it should have the common SQL that he describes available to you. That was also what I had in mind when I asked, because if these values are common you truly will see the gap.

Comment: Obviously you should use a single value for a "blank" value, but I'd recommend that you not make it `Double.MinValue` (or `Double.Epsilon`, which seems to be closer to the values you have), but rather `null`.

Comment: Can you post an example of _relevant_ values?

Comment: Hmmm.  Well I must say the tone is a bit disappointing.  I'm asking what I think is a very straightforward question related to comparing two numbers, and instead I'm getting value assessments of my overall methodology.  One, I might add, that has been in place successfully for over a decade and suits our needs quite nicely.  The reasons for why we do what we do are, frankly, outside the scope of this question, not mention, irrelevant to it.  Thus far, only Mike has put forth helpful advice.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: One trouble with your question is that it's not clear which values are pseudo-null and which are "real".  You've got a few really small normals, a few subnormals, and one pretty big negative number.  We don't know what the field means or what your requirements are, so we can't help you find an intelligent way to solve your problem.

Comment: @tmyklebu Thank you, I'll try to clarify.  It's probable that the "real" values I encounter will all be within a pretty small range, say that of Int16.  I didn't want to simply say that because I already know that I could just hardcode a value and look for less-thans.  I was hoping that someone who understands the math theory and even the storage of floating-point could help me with something less cludgy than that.

Comment: @DonBoitnott:  Well, I don't think you'll find a solution that sucks much less than the one I posted.  By encoding "blank" as DBL_MIN, you've lost all information about what values are "blank" and which are legitimately-produced subnormals/really small normals.  You can't get it back without domain knowledge about what values actually get produced and what values are just too ridiculous.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: You should listen to the advice of these people rather than dismissing it; this system you've got here is astonishingly broken. Now is the time to fix it, not *make its brokenness more consistent*. Non-valid double values should always be represented either as database null, or as double NaN values, **never** as either a very small positive number or a very large negative number.

Comment: @DonBoitnott If you ask a question, expect people to question your entire methodology. All healthy technical communities thrive on criticism. Criticism is not a bad thing. Only through criticism can we improve. So, you can choose to ignore the advice, but don't expect us ever to stop giving it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is utter craziness. Let's look at some of those numbers in detail. These are all tiny numbers just barely larger than zero:

```
2.2250738585072014E-308
```

This is 1 / 2<sup>1022</sup> -- it is a normal double.  This is one of the two "special" numbers in your set; it is the *smallest normal double that is larger than zero*. The rest of the small doubles on your list are subnormal doubles.

```
1.1125369292536007E-308
```

This is 1 / 2<sup>1023</sup> -- it is a subnormal double. This is also a special number; it is *half* the *smallest normal double larger than zero*. (I originally said that it was the largest subnormal double but of course that is not true; see the comments.)

```
3.99285938963E-313
```

This isn't anything special. It's a subnormal double equal to a fraction where the numerator is 154145 and the denominator is a rather large power of two.

```
3.99099435427E-313
```

This isn't anything special either. This time the numerator is 154073.

```
2.104687961E-314
```

This isn't anything special either. The numerator is 2129967929 and the denominator is an even larger power of two.

All the numbers so far have been very close to zero and positive. This number is very far from zero and negative, and therefore stands out:

```
-5.389000690742776E279
```

But again it is nothing special; it is nowhere even close to the negative double with the largest absolute value, which is about -1.79E308, about a billion times larger.

This is a complete mess.

My advice is **stop this madness immediately**.  It makes *absolutely no sense* to use values that are *incredibly close to zero* to represent "blank" values; values that are incredibly close to zero should be rounded to zero, not treated as blanks!

**Double already has a representative for "blank" values, namely Double.NaN -- Not A Number**; it is bizarre to use a *valid value* to represent an *invalid value* when the domain already includes a specific "invalid" value. (Remember that there are actually a large number of distinct NaN bit patterns; use IsNaN to determine if a double is a NaN.)

So my advice is:

- Examine **individually** every number in the database that is a subnormal or very small normal double.  Some of those probably ought to be zero and ended up as tiny values due to rounding errors.  Replace them with zero. The ones that ought to be blank, replace with database null (best practice) or double NaN (acceptable, but not as good as database null.)
- Write a program to find every number in the database that is impossibly large in absolute value and replace it with database null or double NaN.
- Update all clients so that they understand the convention you're using to represent blank values.

Comment: 2**–1023 is not the largest subnormal. It is the largest subnormal with only one bit set. The largest subnormal is 2**–1022 – 2**–1074. (Still crazy though.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Whoops, you are absolutely correct. My bad. I'll correct the text.

Comment: In the end, I accept this answer, because I don't disagree with what all have said about the poor state I'm working in.  In fact, I suspect even @tmyklebu agrees, despite the attempt to answer my direct question.  Thanks to all who answered, the feedback is always welcome.  And thanks to Eric for the explanation of the values, as well as the (chastisement) advice.  :)

Comment: For the result of a subtraction to be nonzero but very small, you must subtract two very small things.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Your comment is incorrect. There are 52 bits of precision in there, which means that the result of a subtraction can be more than a trillion times smaller than either of the operands. You can subtract rather large numbers from each other and still end up with an extraordinarily tiny quantity.

Comment: @EricLippert: Notice that 52 is a lot smaller than 1024, though.  For a-b to have an exponent of, say, -1000, a and b need to have exponents less than -947.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Ah, yes.  Your definition of "very small" and mine were different! :-) I retract my objection.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to check if a `double` is really small and positive or really big, finite, and negative.  (Others have detailed some problems with your approach in the comments; I'm not going to go into that here.)  A test like this:

```
if (d == d && (d > 0 && d < 1e-290 || d < -1e270 && d + d != d))
```

might do roughly what you want.  You'll probably need to tweak the numbers above.  The `d == d` test is checking for `NaN`, while the `d + d != d` test is checking for infinities.

Comment: Though `d==d` is a cheap test for NaN, better would be to call `Double.IsNaN`; that way the future reader of the code who does not understand NaNs will be led to read the documentation, rather than to eliminate the seemingly-unnecessary comparison.

Comment: And similarly for `double.IsNegativeInfinity` and `double.IsPositiveInfinity` -- make the code easy to read rather than using cryptic tricks.

Comment: In addition to Eric's comments, the numbers that he has aren't NaN, and aren't either infinity, so this won't help him.

Comment: @EricLippert:  Cool.  I'll remember that if I ever have to write C# code.

Comment: @Servy: I think you misunderstand the code.  The test succeeds for finite numbers that "kinda look like" the ones OP posted.  The tests for NaNs and infinities are there to deal with doubles that are not finite numbers.